# How to skip the pipeline from job Gitlab

Tags: gitlab-ci

Put together a small test project.

I want in the pipeline:

1. update package version.
2. publish the package in npm.
3. commit and push the changes by skipping the next pipe.

But I ran into such a problem that if I run command `git push --push-option="ci.skip"` locally, the pipeline is skipped. If I launch a push from a job, the next pipeline is not skipped

The git version is 2.11.0 in the job, so you need to use the command `git push --push-option="ci.skip"`

What am I doing wrong?

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: node@sha256:1163a6593bdc407eadb6412aa065393e01135aed67a48a35e3b04182d230e64e

stages:
  - hello
  - update

hello-stage:
  stage: hello
  script: 
    - echo 'Hello World'

update-version:
  stage: update
  when: manual
  script: 
    - echo 'Update version with yarn 2'
    - yarn version check
    - yarn version apply
    - git config --global user.name "$GITLAB_USER_NAME"
    - git config --global user.email "$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL"
    - git remote set-url origin "https://gitlab-ci-token:$GIT_PUSH_TOKEN@$CI_SERVER_HOST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git"
    - git --version # 2.11.0
    - git add .
    - git commit -m 'update package' 
    - npm publish
    - git push --push-option='ci.skip' origin HEAD:master # result pipeline not skipped
```

Result

The pipe is launched to my commit, at 2 stages the package version is updated in the job, commit and push.

Then the pipeline starts again, although it seems to be skipped

[pipelines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2ceP.png)

Comment: Try using double quotes instead of single quotes: `--push-option="ci.skip"`

Comment: @sytech, tried it with double quotes too, but unfortunately it didn't work either

Comment: Hmm. Everything looks correct in the job. Are you using `gitlab.com` or are you self-hosting GitLab? If you are self-hosting, what is the version you are running? As an alternative, you can also try putting `[skip ci]` in the commit message.

Comment: @sytech I use `gitlab.com`.  If you place [ci skip] in the commit message, then the pipeline is skipped. But then, by hand, the pipeline cannot be launched through the "Run pipeline" button. You need to make a new commit without [ci skip]

Comment: The result you described is expected and the behavior of `[ci skip]` in a commit message is identical to the push option.

Comment: I have same problem

Comment: Would "git config --global push.options ci.skip" work to always use ci.skip? Pipelines in my org are started from another tool, never from just a simple push. I'm surprised Atom doesn't allow this option?